# How to convert event.toString() to Map<String, dynamic> in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I used the flutter_callkit_incoming package for incoming calls, and everything works and I want to cast/convert event.toString() to Map so that I can extract a map value of body and extra.

When run this code print(event.toString()), it outputs like this below:

```
{ 
  event: com.hiennv.flutter_callkit_incoming.ACTION_CALL_ACCEPT, 
  body: {
    id: b9be7c0a-1c2a-46e9-ba47-e66e0e2c96ee, 
    nameCaller: Leslie Joe, 
    avatar: http://192.168.43.196:3000/images/1641224008963_image_picker1623631765702357491.jpg, 
    number: 233507300523, 
    type: 0, 
    duration: 30000, 
    extra: {
      caller: 233541395590, 
      callee: 233507300523, 
      callerImage: 1641224008963_image_picker1623631765702357491.jpg, 
      calleeName: Leslie Joe, 
      uuid: b9be7c0a-1c2a-46e9-ba47-e66e0e2c96ee, 
      callType: calling, 
      callerName: Woo Bear,
    }, 
    android: {
      isCustomNotification: true, 
      ringtonePath: ringtone_default, 
      backgroundColor: #0D1117, 
      backgroundUrl: '', 
      actionColor: #0D1117,
    },
  },
}
```

```
final encodedData = json.encode(event.toString());
final decodedData = json.decode(encodedData);
final data = decodedData["body"];
final extraData = decodedData["body"]["extra"];
print(data);
print(extraData);
```

But it gave me errors

```
E/flutter (16521): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'
E/flutter (16521): #0      _MainScreenState.listenerEvent.<anonymous closure>
package:sharpcall/…/screens/main_screen.dart:166
E/flutter (16521): #1      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
E/flutter (16521): #2      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter (16521): #3      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
E/flutter (16521): #4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
E/flutter (16521): #5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
E/flutter (16521): #6      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:123:11)
E/flutter (16521): #7      _MapStream._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:218:10)
E/flutter (16521): #8      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:153:13)
E/flutter (16521): #9      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1434:47)
E/flutter (16521): #10     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1335:19)
E/flutter (16521): #11     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1244:7)
E/flutter (16521): #12     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:341:11)
E/flutter (16521): #13     _DelayedData.perform (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:591:14)
E/flutter (16521): #14     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:706:11)
E/flutter (16521): #15     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:663:7)
E/flutter (16521): #16     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1418:47)
E/flutter (16521): #17     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter (16521): #18     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
E/flutter (16521): #19     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
E/flutter (16521): #20     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1426:13)
E/flutter (16521): #21     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
E/flutter (16521): #22     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1236:7)
E/flutter (16521): #23     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1276:23)
E/flutter (16521): #24     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter (16521): #25     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
```

I need your help on how to convert it to a map correctly. Please check the package's example  [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming/example) Thanks.

Comment: The value returned by `toString()` is not required to be JSON compatible which is also the case here since that value is not even close to be JSON. You need to make your own logic where you put each needed value inside a `Map` which is compatible to `JsonEncoder` and use that to convert the object to `JSON`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your quick solution Sir but it still gives me the same errors. Luckily, I explored the package and found its class called CallEvent with its fields - String name and dynamic body so if the body field is Map, we will be able to get body value as Map from the class.

```
if (event!.body is Map) {
  final extraData = event.body["extra"];
  print(extraData);
}
```

I hope it may help someone else in the future. Thanks! Happy New Year to you all!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the json format of your `event.toString()` output

```json
{
  "event": "com.hiennv.flutter_callkit_incoming.ACTION_CALL_ACCEPT",
  "body": {
    "id": "b9be7c0a-1c2a-46e9-ba47-e66e0e2c96ee",
    "nameCaller": "Leslie Joe",
    "avatar": "http://192.168.43.196:3000/images/1641224008963_image_picker1623631765702357491.jpg",
    "number": 233507300523,
    "type": 0,
    "duration": 30000,
    "extra": {
      "caller": "233541395590",
      "callee": "233507300523",
      "callerImage": "1641224008963_image_picker1623631765702357491.jpg",
      "calleeName": "Leslie Joe",
      "uuid": "b9be7c0a-1c2a-46e9-ba47-e66e0e2c96ee",
      "callType": "calling",
      "callerName": "Woo Bear"
    },
    "android": {
      "isCustomNotification": true,
      "ringtonePath": "ringtone_default",
      "backgroundColor": "#0D1117",
      "backgroundUrl": "",
      "actionColor": "#0D1117"
    }
  }
}
```

You can use an online tool to create classes with `toMap()` & `fromMap()` or `toJson()` & `fromJson()` methods that you can use to produce models of your objects

An example tool is https://app.quicktype.io/ (no null-safety) or https://www.webinovers.com/web-tools/json-to-dart-convertor (null-safety)

For me I like to write my own classes to have control over default values and some more functionalities. So here are the classes I would write to convert your json output

```dart
Event eventFromMap(String str) => Event.fromMap(json.decode(str));

class Event {
  Event({
    this.event,
    this.body,
  });

  String? event;
  Body? body;

  factory Event.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Event(
    event: json["event"],
    body: json["body"] == null ? null : Body.fromMap(json["body"]),
  );
}

class Body {
  Body({
    this.id,
    this.nameCaller,
    this.avatar,
    this.number,
    this.type,
    this.duration,
    this.extra,
    this.android,
  });

  String? id;
  String? nameCaller;
  String? avatar;
  int? number;
  int? type;
  int? duration;
  Extra? extra;
  Android? android;

  factory Body.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Body(
    id: json["id"],
    nameCaller: json["nameCaller"],
    avatar: json["avatar"],
    number: json["number"],
    type: json["type"],
    duration: json["duration"],
    extra: json["extra"] == null ? null : Extra.fromMap(json["extra"]),
    android: json["android"] == null ? null : Android.fromMap(json["android"]),
  );
}

class Android {
  Android({
    this.isCustomNotification = false, // add your custom default value
    this.ringtonePath,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.backgroundUrl,
    this.actionColor,
  });

  bool isCustomNotification;
  String? ringtonePath;
  String? backgroundColor;
  String? backgroundUrl;
  String? actionColor;

  factory Android.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Android(
    isCustomNotification: json["isCustomNotification"],
    ringtonePath: json["ringtonePath"],
    backgroundColor: json["backgroundColor"],
    backgroundUrl: json["backgroundUrl"],
    actionColor: json["actionColor"],
  );
}

class Extra {
  Extra({
    this.caller,
    this.callee,
    this.callerImage,
    this.calleeName,
    this.uuid,
    this.callType,
    this.callerName,
  });

  String? caller;
  String? callee;
  String? callerImage;
  String? calleeName;
  String? uuid;
  String? callType;
  String? callerName;

  factory Extra.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Extra(
    caller: json["caller"],
    callee: json["callee"],
    callerImage: json["callerImage"],
    calleeName: json["calleeName"],
    uuid: json["uuid"],
    callType: json["callType"],
    callerName: json["callerName"],
  );
}
```

Now if you type

```dart
final event = eventFromMap(rawEvent.toString()); // Your response
```

You can use `event.body?.extra?.caller` for example to access data with autocomplete benefit which is better than maps in my opinion